# How to add scrollbar in modal?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have my modal in css and I wanted to add a scroll to it when there are too many elements but I don't know how.

It looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Txrn.png

How add right scrollbar?

```
CSS: https://pastebin.com/S0dFjdX6
```

Comment: Validations are there for a reason... When you bypass them you break community rules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an overflow-y to your modal. That should easily fix the issue like so; assuming you have your modal class as my-modal, your css can be something like;

```
.my-modal{ overflow-y: scroll;}
```

This works for most elements that require scrolling effects.

Comment: Check this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sz35.png and my .modal css: https://pastebin.com/kjVsANgW

this scrollbar is not working :/

Comment: @Darek from your code, on line 9, you have "overflow:hidden", change it to "overflow-y:scroll"

Comment: Still not working - https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6yK5.png

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. I did some research in my css and I did it. I got what I wanted! - https://i.stack.imgur.com/put9b.png